# saving many DF into different Excel file, Python pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, export-to-excel

This Python code is meant to process and analyze sales data from an Excel file. It should deliver separate Excel files with quotes from each SalesContact. However, the code saves a single DataFrame that contains data from all SalesContacts, instead of grouping and saving each SalesContact's info into its respective output file.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


#Modules
def clean_column(df,column):
    df[column] = df[column].str.upper()
    df[column] = df[column].str.replace('[^A-Z]', '')
    return df


def days_until(target_date_str):
    target_date =datetime.strptime(target_date_str, "%m/%d/%Y")
    days_left = (target_date - current_date).days
    return days_left


def status(row):
    if row['ExtendedPrice'] < 50000 and row['Overdue Days'] >= -10:
        return 'Recall client'
    elif row['ExtendedPrice'] <= 50000 and row['Overdue Days'] >= 5:
        return 'Recall client'
    else:
        return 'Did not recall client'


def get_file_path(file_name):
    return "path" + str(file_name) + "_Quote.xlsx"


#path to save main df (final_df)
#Crear ruta y nombre
current_date = datetime.now().date()
file_path = get_file_path(current_date)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='xlsxwriter')

#file path and sheet name to access

xl = pd.ExcelFile('excel_file_path.xlsx')
df = xl.parse('Quotes')

#filtered Converted values (Sales Quotes)

filtered_df = df[df['Status'] == 'Converted']
unnamed_3_list = filtered_df['QuoteNumber'].tolist()
sent_filtered_df = df[df['Status'] == 'Sent']
sent_filtered_df = sent_filtered_df[~sent_filtered_df['QuoteNumber'].isin(unnamed_3_list)]

#filtered Sent values (Quotes that aren't sales yet)

sent_df = sent_filtered_df.sort_values(['QuoteNumber', 'Version'], ascending=[True, False])
grouped = sent_df.groupby('QuoteNumber')
max_values = grouped['Version'].max()
max_df = grouped.apply(lambda x: x[x['Version'] == x['Version'].max()])

final_df = pd.concat([filtered_df, max_df])

#USD to MXN

for index, each in final_df.iterrows():
    if 'USD' in each['Organization']:
        final_df.at[index,'ExtendedPrice'] *= 18

#create DFs as CRM for each SalesContact summarizing all items from QuoteNumber

grouped = final_df.groupby('QuoteNumber').agg({'ExtendedPrice': 'sum', 'SalesContact': 'first', 'QuoteDate': 'first'})
grouped['ExtendedPrice'] =grouped['ExtendedPrice'].round()
price_df = grouped
salesperson_grouped = price_df.groupby('SalesContact')
grouped_dfs = {}

for name, group in salesperson_grouped:
    if 'QuoteNumber' in group.columns:
        grouped_dfs[name] = pd.DataFrame({'QuoteNumber': group['QuoteNumber'], 'ExtendedPrice': group['ExtendedPrice'], 'QuoteDate': group['QuoteDate']})
        grouped_dfs[name] = grouped_dfs[name][grouped_dfs[name]['ExtendedPrice'] <= 100000]
        grouped_dfs[name]['FollowupDate'] = ''
        grouped_dfs[name]['Overdue Days'] = grouped_dfs[name]['QuoteDate'].apply(days_until)
        grouped_dfs[name]['Status'] = grouped_dfs[name].apply(status, axis=1)
        grouped_dfs[name]['Comments'] = ''
    with pd.ExcelWriter(get_file_path(name), engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        if name in grouped_dfs:
            grouped_dfs[name].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name, index=False)
        final_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Quotes', index=False)
        writer._save()

#saving all data
writer._save()
```

I want to know which part of the code isn't working as expected and how to solve it

Comment: You've provided a snippet but not a minimum working example -- I don't have your xlsx file. You could create a simple xlsx file at the top of the snippet.

Comment: the `writer` is a file handle associated with the `with open(...` but on the last line `writer` is referenced outside the scope of the `with open(...`.